# Localizing Info.plist variable with appended string

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, info.plist

I'm trying to localize the name of an app while still being able to append a string depending on the build configuration. So currently it is set up as:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${PRODUCT_NAME}${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX}</string>
```

That setting is defined as:

[image: Build Setting]

This way we can add the suffix to the app for our different beta builds. The problem is that when we try to localize the app display name in the localized `InfoPlist.strings` like so

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "Localized App Name";
```

We overwrite the value stored in the `Info.plist`, and lose the suffix character. Is there any good way around this? We would like to avoid having multiple `Info.plist` files.

Comment: How do you overwrite the value stored in the Info.plist? You do it manually?

Comment: Can't comment because of lack of reputation, sorry. @Romain answer is correct but i spent all day to make it work. The thing is put script AFTER Compile Sources phase and Copy Bundle Resources phase. Hope it gonna help someone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need a custom script to do this. Here is one that is working for me

```
PREFIX_IDENTIFIER="=com.mycompany.bundlenameprefix="
PREFIX=""

if [ $CONFIGURATION == "Debug" ]
then
    PREFIX="α "
fi

if [ $CONFIGURATION == "Enterprise" ]
then
    PREFIX="β "
fi

for i in `dirname "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`/*.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
do
    plutil -convert json "$i"
    sed -i -e "s/${PREFIX_IDENTIFIER}/${PREFIX}/g" "$i"
    plutil -convert binary1 "$i"
done
```

Then in your InfoPlist.strings add a prefix to the bundle name like so

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "=com.mycompany.bundlenameprefix=My App";
```

Comment: Great answer. A note for anyone troubleshooting this, if your target build directory has spaces in it you need to enclose the output of `dirname` in quotes