# Localise App display name that have append suffix

Tags: ios, swift, localization, translation, plist

I have a issue with getting app display name to include the appending suffix when adding localisation to `InfoStrings.plist`.

I have add different `scheme` and `User-Defined` attribute. So in my info.plist, i have `App Name $(BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX)` in my `CFBundleDisplayName`. It will append a `-S` to my app name when running on development scheme and normal app name on release scheme that i created. Everything is working well.

However, when I try to translate the app name, it does not work anymore. So in my `infoPlist.strings`, I tried the following:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name ";
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name $(BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX)";
```

Both does not append the `-S` anymore when I run on development scheme. Does anyone know how I could still do that? Like maybe how to get the `$(Bundle_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX)` to be read in the `infoPlist.strings`.

More specifically, how do I include a preprocessor in `InfoPlist.strings`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [answer to your question in another thread, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886342/1311272), but it says you need a scrip for this.

**How you create different suffixes (not what was asked for)**
Here is how you set up different display name of your app based on the your scheme. You can do this by setting up different `configurations`. Go to the project settings -> select the project (not the target) -> `Info` tab -> then create as many configurations you would like. Maybe one for `Production`, `Debug` and one for `Beta` releases.

Then select your `Target` -> `Build settings` tab -> Enter `display` in search. Under `User defined` you can create your own variable, call it e.g. `BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX`. Give it different values for `Production`, `Debug` and `Beta`.

Open your `Info.plist` file, under `Bundle display name`, your see maybe `MyApp`, append the string `${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX}` so it makes `MyApp${BUNDLE_DISPLAY_NAME_SUFFIX}`.

Finally configure your schemes to use the correct configuration. You probably want to use `Production` for `Archive` and `Debug` for `Debug`.

[Here is an image of the User defined variable](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2747276/StackOverflowAnswers/Swift_Display_Name.png)

Comment: Hi @Sajjon, I could already do this. But my question is how can I localise it and still maintain the ability to do it. Because in the infoplist.strings the ${Bundle_Display}  don't work.

Comment: But I have three different languages and it still works.

Comment: For the app name with different language?

Comment: Or do you mean that you want the Display name to be DEPENDENT on the configuration AND the language. In my case I have three configurations and three languages, so do you in this case want nine different display names? :S

Comment: I have 2 configuration the app name just need to be localise with the ability to add the -S behind.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be depend on my configuration scheme as well

Comment: Okay I am sorry I misunderstood your question, I think this should be possible, let me get back to you and then update my answer!

Comment: Cool, look like is workable. I was expecting a script as so far I find Xcode does not do preprocessor for InfoPlist.strings. Will give it a try once I am home

Comment: Are you using fastlane per any chance? It would be nice to write that script as a fastlane action :)

Comment: Yes, to be exact, I am using fastlane on Bitwise actually.

Comment: It is only the last part in the for loop, that I am unsure of how to do in ruby, but should not be too possible I guess. Let me know if you get it working :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to localize the display name of the app for many different schemes? I am struggling to find out how to do it.