# How to use variable from Info.plist inside my InfoPlist.strings file?

Tags: xcode, localization, info.plist

I am trying to use the `${PRODUCT_NAME}` variable from Info.plist but use it in my localized InfoPlist.strings file which will show the app name when the notification pops up. Is this even possible?

When I try to do it this way, I get a popup with the proper language but it shows `$(PROGRAM_NAME)` instead of `"My App Name"` ...

```
    Info.plist:
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} would like to use your current location while using the app and in the background</string>

    InfoPlist.strings (EN):
    "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "${PRODUCT_NAME} would like to use your current location while using the app and in the background";

    InfoPlist.strings (FR):
    "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" = "${PRODUCT_NAME} souhaiteraient utiliser votre emplacement actuel en utilisant l'application et en arrière-plan";
```

[image]

Comment: try `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` instead.

Comment: same result.. I will post a picture

Comment: I'm stuck at the same situation. Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: Expected something on this question. I wonder if there is any way out,

Comment: Did anyone ever figure out this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27886342/8874833

I've created a custom run script and adapted it this way:

```
for i in `dirname "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`/*.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
do
    # replace App name in App bundle's info.plist 
    plutil -convert json "$i"
    sed -i -e 's/$(MY_APP_NAME)/'${MY_APP_NAME}'/g' "$i"
    plutil -convert binary1 "$i"
    rm "$i-e"

done
```

**MY_APP_NAME** is a user defined value in xcconfig